# Open-source mobility device management solution for isolated network

Tags: android, open-source, mdm

does anyone know of an open source MDM for Android, which runs on an isolated network (LAN). Hence, the devices and server won't have external access to the internet.

This, unfortunately excludes any MDM which makes use of Google Cloud Messaging as its push services.

It requires very basic functioning, such as ping (to see whether the device/s are alive) and update apps.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can look at similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612067/open-source-mobile-device-management-solution-for-android

Your best bet would be to get http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/ and modify it to not use Google Cloud Messaging. Most of the time GCM is used just to let device know that some new commands/settings are available for it on the server. You can change it to use your own home grown broadcasting method.

Comment: Hi @Victor thank you for your response. I have looked at that question, however all their solutions use cloud services.
I do currently have a WSO2 EMM up and sunning. However I am struggling to remove GCM and replace it with MQTT Mosquitto and Paho.

Am I missing a more straight forward approach? My experience is still very limited and I appreciate any help and guidance.

Comment: Frankly, my exposure to something like MQTT Mosquitto and Paho is absolutely zero. I would say, as a first step you can change Android clients to do just a periodic checkin (this will buy you some time to figure out a solution to send other messages from the server to devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace GCM with MQTT then you have to implement local notification in the android agent side and do a polling to server to check is there any pending operation. If there are pending operations you will get a response to device through MQTT. Any way implementation level you have to some more work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the WSO2 EMM might migrate to MQTT protocol in the future. Anyway for now if you really need it you can take the source code and implement it in your own which is not a big deal since the code is free/open source. Anyway do let us know if you stuck in any position when implementing. Also you may consider it contributing back to the project for others benefit.

(FYI I am a core team member in WSO2 EMM)

Comment: Hi @Dilshan,thank you for your response, I am aware that you and Kasun are WSO2 EMM core members, he has also assisted me earlier on and I will gladly contribute once I have successfully implemented what I am aiming. However I am fairly new to Android and such so I need to learn some first and sue to time constraints I will try and change the apk so that it systematically polls the server as Victor suggested (I am aware that this will kill the battery - temporary solution). And then if time allows it, implement MQTT as I also have no experience with that either.